# Issue with checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer

When a customer is registered and is signed in with our web site he/she is not able to finish the ordering. Customer is being automatically signed out after clicking on button "processed to checkout". But when customer is not signed in, here is able to finish the order. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it sounds like it could be a form key issue. The following html may need to be added within the form on that page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>"/>
```

Comment: I will give it a try, and let you know. Thank you Brian for your effort.

Comment: Hi Brian, I just tried the solution your suggestion, and there is already above code in my html template. Same as you provided. Any other suggestion? Thanks.